# python receive filename not contents - variable refers to (python3)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script which I want to pass to odo. odo takes a filename as input, as I need to tidy the csv up first I pass it through a script to create a new file which I reference with a variable.

How can I get just the filename from the variable so I can pass it as an argument to odo(from blaze project).

You can see here that from this script pasted to ipython I get the entire contents of the file.

```
In [8]: %paste
from odo import odo
import pandas as pd
from clean2 import clean
import os

filegiven = '20150704RHIL0.csv'
myFile = clean(filegiven)
toUse = (filegiven + '_clean.csv')
print(os.path.realpath(toUse))

## -- End pasted text --
Surfin' Safari 3 0
... Many lines later
Search Squad (NZ) 4 5
C:\Users\sayth\Repos\Notebooks\20150704RHIL0.csv_clean.csv # from print
```

I just need to be able to get this name so my script could be, where myFile would give odo the filename not contents.

```
from odo import odo
import pandas as pd
from clean2 import clean


filegiven = '20150704RHIL0.csv'
myFile = clean(filegiven)

odo(myFile, pd.DataFrame)
```

**Solution**

this is how I solved it there would be better ways likely.

```
from odo import odo
import pandas as pd
from clean2 import clean
import os.path

filegiven = '20150704RHIL0.csv'
clean(filegiven)
fileName = os.path.basename(filegiven)
fileNameSplit = fileName.split(".")
fileNameUse = fileNameSplit[0] + '_clean.' + fileNameSplit[1]


odo(fileNameUse, pd.DataFrame)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in a standard `python3` console.  It prints `'/home/kjc/tmp/20150704RHIL0.csv_clean.csv'`, exactly as you would expect from feeding the string `'20150704RHIL0.csv_clean.csv'` to `realpath` while in my temp directory.  Was there a copy-and-paste error in your question?  The first code block never uses `myFile`, nor does it ever _open_ a file... unless `clean` opens the file for you.  (What _is_ `clean2.clean`, anyway?)  Finally, since you build the name of the output file yourself, why not just pass that string to `odo`?

Comment: Yes but the file is actually /home/kjc/tmp/20150704RHIL0.clean.csv I can't pick up the filename created from calling the first script clean.

Answer (score 1):

To get a filename from a file object (assumings its standard File object in Python created using `open()` ) , you can use `name` variable in it.

Example -

```
>>> f = open("a.py",'r')
>>> f.name
'a.py'
```

Please note, for your situation this is unnecessary, maybe you can have your `clean(filegiven)` return `filename` instead of file object, and then if you really need the file object you can open it in your script.